# Oracle ojdbc (19.17.0.0) dependency issues in Spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, ojdbc

I am trying to use Oracle client 19.17.0.0 in my Spring boot app,
I added the following to the pom,

```
<properties>
    <oracle-database.version>19.17.0.0</oracle-database.version>
</properties>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>${oracle-database.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

When I build the app, it refers to sprint-boot-dependencies-3.0.7.pom, this pom contains the  dependency to ojdbc-pom, and it does not have version 19.17.0.0 available in that folder, it has 19.18.0.0 and 19.16.0.0 though.

The build failed with a non-resolvable dependency error.
Any ideas for how to fix this? or simply just not call the sprint-boot-dependencies-3.0.7.pom?

Thanks.

Comment: The best way to deal with dependencies is to generate pom.xml using https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Why do you insist on this version?

Comment: This is a corporate project, currently we only have 19.3 and 19.17 client available.

Comment: I can see it in maven central https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc-bom/19.17.0.0/overview

Comment: @Jean de Lavarene, thanks, I will check.